# Getting corresponding data from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm rather new with excel and no good at VB, and couldn't find a way to solve the following:
I have one sheet which contains data about articles and another sheet which contains only the title of the article and the amount of times it is cited.

For example the first sheet contains data in these columns:

```
First Author    Second Author   Other Authors   Publication Year    Title   Published In    More Info
```

and the second in these:

```
Title      Count
```

I want to copy all the data from the first sheet to the corresponding row on the second sheet (based on the article title). Some titles may appear twice on the first sheet, but should only be copied once to the second. Also, it would be good if all lines that were copied from the first sheet to the second would be highlighted so that I could see if there were any mistakes.

A VBA solution is also welcome.

Comment: It would be great to have the workbook to review but it seems to me you can do this with vlookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for VBA. This is a simple `INDEX-MATCH` combination.

### **Set-up:**

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

**Enter the following formula to Sheet2!C2, drag down and right:**

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$G,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$E:$E,0),MATCH(Sheet2!C$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$1,0))
```

**Result:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: this worked very well thanks! however, in my results there were 160 rows of N/A, even though the titles match the data in the first sheet. I couldn't find any recurring problem that would cause this, have you any idea why it happened?

Comment: Possibly a misapplication of the formula above. If you don't have any sensitive info in your file, can you kindly upload a copy to wikisend or the like and post a link here? I'll take a personal look. :)

Comment: loaded a sample to wikiupload, wikisend didn't work for me. The link is: http://www.wikiupload.com/EX8DCFHEZ90UEGE, thanks!

Comment: Reason for the error is simple: the titles don't match. They have to be ***exactly*** the same, unless you're going to do some massive `IF-THEN` stuff. Just make sure that there are no extra spaces in the titles in either columns, and they have to be pat down exact. Otherwise, it will necessitate a more complicated formula. Anyway, re-uploaded and download the fixed file [here](http://www.wikiupload.com/5GNXMI9FNCX33LB).

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give you an Idea how to match the cells. Assuming you have the title in column 10 in sheet1 and column 1 in sheet2

```
dim i as integer
dim j as integer
for i = 1 to 'number of rows in sheet1
    for j = 1 to 'number of rows in sheet2
        if sheet1.cells(i, 1) = sheet2.cells(j, 1) then
            'do what ever you want with the matching records
        end if
    next j
next i
```